# How can I get name of HTTP Request from field Name with BeanShell?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I Need to get to variable field from http request which is called Name.
If anyone could give my examples how can I get other fields such as : Path, Server name or IP using beanshell?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

1. Add [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the request
2. Use following code lines to get the required values:

   ```
   String name = sampler.getName(); // get parent sampler name
   String path = sampler.getUrl().getPath(); // get path
   String url = sampler.getUrl().getHost();  // get IP or hostname
   ```

   you can also store values into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) if required like

   ```
   vars.put("name", name);
   ```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for comprehensive information on using Beanshell scripting in your JMeter test.

Answer (score 2):

Below code can give you the HTTP Request Name field value

`ctx.getCurrentSampler().getName()`

Comment: keep getting lines like `String name = sampler.xxxx` from google, but none of the posts mentioned about what is `sampler`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it without beanshell. Just use inside your sampler
${__samplerName()}

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__samplerName